# Registering for push notifications in iOS why call

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

Hey I am registering for push notifications using the following two methods:

```
func registerForPushNotifications() {
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) {
                (granted, error) in
                guard granted else { return }
                self.getNotificationSettings()
            }
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
            // iOS 9 and below register
        }
    }

    func getNotificationSettings() {
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings { (settings) in
                guard settings.authorizationStatus == .authorized else { return }
                UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
            }
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
    }
```

`registerForPushNotifications` is called in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`. This is code from a tutorial. My question is, why do I have to check `settings.authorizationStatus == .authorized`? If a user declines to use push notifications on the first app launch and then changes this setting to approved in the push notifications settings `granted` will be true in `registerForPushNotifications`. Why the need for the second check?

Comment: To show an alert if the user doesn't do it from settings too.

Comment: It is just to check whether your app has already been registered for push notification on the current device or not. If already registered then it will not register every time of app launch. By the way as per your scenario you can omit this check and implement your own logic to register for push!

Comment: @Tuhin but the first check `UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization` does this. Why the need for the `settings.authorizationStatus == .authorized` check?

Comment: @Kex On the above granted indicates that user has given authentication for push whether the second check i.e. settings.authorizationStatus == .authorized is checking the authorization type I guess. There are several types of status of these which you can find iOS docs.